# Findbugs doesn't detect all infinite loops

Tags: java, maven, loops, findbugs, infinite

I am using Findbugs plugin with Maven but when I execute this plugin, doesn't detect all infinite loops..

The code that i am testing is the next:

```
public void infinite_1(){
    while(true){
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}

public void infinite_2(){
    boolean x = true;
    while(x){
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}

public void infinite_3(){
    int x = 2;
    while(x == 2){
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}

public void infinite_4(){
    while(1 < 2){
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}

public void infinite_5(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i--){
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

And Findbugs only detects second and third methods.. 
What's the problem? Should i use other Maven plugin to be able to detect all infinite loops?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create a program that detects every infinite loop, therefore neither findbugs nor anything else will be able to do it. These tools work in some cases and they fail in most of the cases.

This problem quickly leads to the halting problem, there was a discussion about a similar topic recently here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/49332/proof-that-dead-code-cannot-be-detected-by-compilers?newsletter=1&nlcode=415593%7ca8d0 you may read it if you feel curious about the theoretical background.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you do want to have an endless loop, there's nothing wrong with it. For example, you are started some daemon thread which should work always until your application finishes. Or you rely on the `InterruptedException` (or some other exception) which should break your loop. When you write `while(true)` you express the clear *intention* to make the loop infinite, so it's unlikely to be a bug. After all FindBugs is a tool to detect possible bugs, not a tool to detect infinite loops. That's why the case #1 is not reported.

On the other hand, cases #2 and #3 look like bugs, because it looks like developer actually wanted to modify the variable in a loop, but forgot to do it. So FindBugs reports it. Even if it's intended to be infinite, you should consider making this more clear using `while(true)` or `for(;;)` syntax.

Case #4 is somewhat tricky. The `1 < 2` expression is a [compile time constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28): it's evaluated to `true` during the compilation to bytecode, thus looking into bytecode you cannot distinguish `while(true)` and `while(1 < 2)`. FindBugs is a bytecode analysis tool, it almost never looks into sources, so it simply does not see the difference. As it was decided not to report every `while(true)`, FindBugs cannot also report `while(1 < 2)`. On the other hand, I hardly can imagine that somebody wrote `while(1 < 2)` by mistake in real code. FindBugs is a tool to find real bugs in real code, not artificial "thought-up" bugs.

As for case #5, it's quite difficult (though not impossible) to analyze it and say whether the loop is infinite or not. It's difficult even for you: you think that this loop is infinite, but actually it's not. It will have roughly 2 billions of iterations until `i` overflows and condition will become false. It *looks like* a bug, though. FindBugs just has no ready pattern to detect it. You may suggest a patch to the developers.

Comment: It is impossible to check if a loop is infinite in general. Consider this
void collatz(int n){
while (n > 1) { if (n%2 == 0) n /= 2; else n = 3*n+1; }
}
Weather this loop is finite or infinite is an open problem in mathematics.

Comment: @edofic, of course I know. I had computer science course. Who do you think upvoted another answer? :-)

Comment: @edofic, by the way your concrete example can be statically analyzed (though no analyzer would do this, seriously). Don't forget that `int` has a finite domain and it can be checked in finite time. In fact it *is* checked and known that for any `int` number this loop will finish.